Golang Указание метода веб сервера
Есть http.HandleFunc который запрашивает данные от клиента. Есть способ как-то указать, что этот метод работает только через GET или POST?
http.HandleFunc("/olock_open/all", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  username, password, ok := r.BasicAuth()
  check_auth := authfunc.CheckAuth(w, username, password, ok)
  if !check_auth {
   return
  }

  for i := 0; i < len(online_locks_list_active); i++ {
   _, err := tcpcommandolock.SendCommandOlock(online_locks_list_active[i].Connection, []byte{0x02, 0x0A, 0x30, 0x51, 0x03, 0x90})
   if err != nil {
    syslogging.LogToSys("Error, can't send command to BU"+online_locks_list_active[i].Address+": "+err.Error(), "Info")
   }
  }
  defer r.Body.Close()
 })```


Да
http.HandleFunc("POST /olock_open/all", func(...){...})

Перед url необходимо указать метод. Работает с версии 1.22

Большое спасибо!!!
